# Does a standing desk prevent the health issues with sitting?

Tags: sitting

It's not clear to me if the health issues related to sitting are due to not standing as much or not moving as much (or both). If the issue is that you're not moving much, standing doesn't seem it would help much. Does using a standing desk at work prevent the health issues with sitting?

Comment: Which health issue are you asking about? There are several.

Comment: Any of the health issues associated with sitting.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this NPR article](https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2016/03/17/470713717/stand-to-work-if-you-like-but-dont-brag-about-its-benefits) in a meta-analysis it seems it's not yet clear:

> there isn't really any evidence that standing is better than sitting,
>   Verbeek adds.

And:

> Carr says the finding of the Cochrane review doesn't mean that
>   standing desks and variations are useless. It just means there hasn't
>   been enough study of the desks to say either way. "The state of the
>   science is definitely early," he says. "There needs to be longer
>   studies with more people to get a good sense these desks actually
>   cause people to stand."

Also [this answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/152/11685) says movement is more important than standing:

> it's the inactivity with sitting that is unhealthy. You can
>   stand and be inactive just as well (standing desk).

Comment: While I agree with what you wrote so far: have you found something about more dynamic sitting postures, angles; sitting as the most 'unnatural' position a human body can take? ('Chairs being such a recent invention')